# Unable to redirect "Thread" or "Fork" commands in ruby script to Jenkins

Tags: ruby, bash, jenkins, chef-infra

We have a script that runs chef-client from a bash console.

This output is supposed to be redirected to jenkins which should display the logs of the chef-client run, which is not happening.

We use  `Thread.new` and Fork to run this chef-client run...

```
Thread.new {system "/usr/bin/knife ssh -x abc -P xyz \"role:#{somerole}\" \"sudo chef-client -o role[#{somerole}]\" > test.log 2>&1 &"}
```

How can the logs of "Thread" and "Fork" commands be displayed via jenkins??

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

The `&` at the end of your commands makes it run in background, detaching from the ssh terminal, so it ends up as soon as it is launched and terminate the connexion.

In your command, you redirect the output to a file named test.log, so there's nothing on the terminal anyway.

If you want to log to a file, configure the `client.rb` to log to it instead of redirecting to a file, chef will log and output to screen at the same time.

I can't tell for Thread.new, but there's already 2 reason for not seeing anything with the command you show.

Comment: Thank u so much Tensibai, I tried it without & at the end and it doesn't work...i should have taken it away while posting the question...Does Thread.new {} spawn any terminal or shell or some such thing..

Comment: I said the `&`was not the only problem, redirecting to a file won't send anything to the terminal too.